# Edit files on server with Eclipse

Tags: linux, remote-access

I'm trying to figure out how to do this with Eclipse.  We currently run SVN and everything works great, but I'd really like to cut my SSH requests in half and use Eclipse to modify some files directly on the server.  I'm using the below build of eclipse... how can I do this?

```
Eclipse for PHP Developers

Build id: 20100218-1602
```

**Update**

I have no intention of eliminating SVN from the equation, but when we need to make a hotfix, or run a specific report or function as a one-time thing, I'd much rather use Eclipse than terminal for modifying that kind of thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at [How can I use a remote workspace over SSH?](http://wiki.eclipse.org/TM_and_RSE_FAQ#How_can_I_use_a_remote_workspace_over_SSH.3F) on the Eclipse wiki. I'm just quoting the summary below (read the whole section):

> **Summing up**, I would recommend the
>   following (in order of preference):
>
> 1. VNC or NX when available remotely, Eclipse can be started remotely and
>      the network is fast enough (try it
>      out).
> 2. Mounted filesystem (Samba or SSHFS) when possible, the network is fast
>      enough and the workspace is not too
>      huge.
> 3. rsync when offline editing is desired, sufficient tooling is
>      available locally, and no merge issues
>      are expected (single user scenario).
> 4. [RSE](http://www.eclipse.org/dsdp/tm) on very slow connections or huge workspaces where minimal data
>      transfer is desired.
> 5. [EFS](http://tmober.blogspot.com/2007/04/target-management-m6-efs-and-webinar.html) on fast connections when all tooling supports it, and options
>      like VNC or mounted filesystem or
>      rsync are not available.

But whatever you'll experiment, don't bypassing the version control system.

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like [SSHFS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SSHFS), but really, it's a better idea to use some kind of source control system instead of editing files directly on the server. If Subversion isn't sufficient, perhaps you might try a DVCS like Git or Mercurial.